# Firstly, Spider ID? Also possible relation to ~100+ serious bite reactions in past 1-2yrs

Tags: species-identification

Might have been occuring since day 1 in new residence about 2 years ago. Bites are painful to touch, when fresh, very odd sort of void filled with black stuff under skin which regularly shows fang type trackmarks.(golf ball size swelling, pussing, twin &/or parallel punctures wounds, black(necrotic?) Substance under hardened skin cap as healing, long term healing) Spider found in nightstand drawer, maybe stranded in bottom of SS can cooler.
I have many pics of the live spider in a jar. Thankyou...;)>[image: spider]!

Comment: Please add information such as size of spider and your geographical location. Clearer pictures of the spider would also help.

Comment: Thank you for reply... I am located at Northern border of 54121 zip code, I'll transfer it to a better container than old mason jar and try for better pics... was having issues uploading here,

Comment: Will confirm and post better pics asap, ... but body appears to be ~15mm and leg spread in standard stance ~35mm. I'm not sure, but it may have shrunk a little after spending the last few days in an empty jar.  I will say that thing is very aware and has great sight through that distorted glass, it tracks and follows me around the room from 10-15 feet away even after 2 days of ignorance to it...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1By0VjOmEnhSb-zVieAbHfEjwVg2jpnYf

Comment: The link above has a dozen of the best pics

Comment: Holy fk 100 bites sounds like a spider drive thru.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [wolf spider](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_spider). It grows from about 1cm to 5cm long. Wolf spiders are usually gray with brown to dark gray markings. It does not spin webs, instead it actively hunts it's prey. Wolf spiders are agile, robust and have excellent eyesight$^1$. That is why you have noticed that it is quite aware of your movements.

***Hogna radiata:***

[image: Hogna]

***Alopecosa Kochi:***

[image: Alopecosa]

The bite of this spider leaves prominent marks$^2$.

[image: bite mark]

In severe cases, the surrounding area may develop redness, swelling, and even ulcers that spread beyond just the bite location. Allergic reactions may cause even more severe symptoms in some people$^2$.

[image: inflammation due to bite]

Since the wolf spider is not poisonous its bite can be treated by cleaning the area with soap and water and then placing a bandage over it$^2$.

**Note:**

I am unable to identify the exact genus of the spider. I believe it could be [Hogna](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogna) or [Alopecia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alopecosa). Someone more knowledgeable could inform me.

**References:**

1.[Wikepedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_spider)

2.[Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/wolf-spider-bite#treatment)

Comment: That is what I was leaning towards too, it's not identical to any pictures I can find but it's closed of course a lot of the other ones are close to each other being different spiders too.   I don't understand why I'm getting consistently bitten over such a long period of time, all seasons.  Some bites are much worse than others, but fang marks and spread are pretty consistant. But doesn't seem like nesting type, more territorial, I would guess.  I bomb the place three times w/ double doses: doesn't seem to have much effect, not permanent one for sure. I've added bite pics to drive link

Comment: @CustomCreations I am not experienced enough to know the answers to these questions. Hopefully someone else will give a solution to your issue.